# Vim background color "dark" = "black"? or I didn't install correctly?

Tags: vim, macvim

I added a color theme expected to be, in which the background color is lighter than black.:
[image]

But my my color theme looks complete dark. Whats wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your profile settings of your terminal app? Looks like you are running the standard mac terminal. [Adding color to the terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/21/add-color-to-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/)